# SQL for recursive self linked table

Tags: sql-server

I have a BOM formula table which list BOM item with its’ component.  Table has two fields: BOM and component fields.  Component item might be another formula.  For example:

```
BOM, Component
A1, C1
A1, C2
A1, C3

A2, C4
A2, C5

C2, C6
C2, C7

C7, C8
C7, C9
C7, C10
```

Item A1 has C1, C2 and C3 component.

- C1 and C3 are raw material
- while C2 is BOM type and it has C6 and C7 components.

How to use SQL to list the recursive type query to find out A1 item all raw material?  Recursive level is unknown. In this case, A1 has C1, C3, C6, C8, C9, and C10 raw material.

Update question by follow example:

BOM is an item which is assembled from component item.  Need query to get BOM item's all raw material component to do production material plan.

A1 is a BOM item which is assembled from C1, C2, and C3.
C2 is a BOM item which is assembled from C6 and C7.
C7 is a BOM item which is assembled from C8, C9 and C10.

Component for BOM item A1 is C1, C3, C6, C8, C9 and C10.  C2 and C7 are BOM item and they are not raw material items.

The output will be:

```
A1 C1
A1 C3
A1 C6
A1 C8
A1 C9
A1 C10

A2 C4
A2 C5
```

Below records are option.  It can be on the output or not on the output.

```
C2 C6
C2 C8
C2 C9
C2 C10

C7 C8
C7 C9
C7 C10
```

Comment: Hi YellowLarry, I just updated my answer. I do not think, that there is a recursive ad-hoc approach. You might go the cursor or CLR path...

Comment: @Shnugo I think my recursive solution should do it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza great! Voter it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:** Now will show only `BOM` that are not part of another component

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0d0d/11)**

```
WITH DirectReports (BOM, Component, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.BOM, e.Component, 0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.BOM AS e
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT d.BOM, e.Component, Level + 1
    FROM dbo.BOM AS e
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
            ON e.BOM = d.Component
           AND d.Level = Level
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT DR.BOM, DR.Component, DR.Level, B.Component
FROM DirectReports DR
LEFT JOIN BOM  B
       ON DR.BOM = B.Component
WHERE B.Component IS NULL       
ORDER BY BOM
GO
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| BOM | Component | Level | Component |
|-----|-----------|-------|-----------|
|  A1 |        C1 |     0 |    (null) |
|  A1 |        C2 |     0 |    (null) |
|  A1 |        C3 |     0 |    (null) |
|  A1 |        C6 |     1 |    (null) |
|  A1 |        C7 |     1 |    (null) |
|  A1 |        C8 |     2 |    (null) |
|  A1 |        C9 |     2 |    (null) |
|  A1 |       C10 |     2 |    (null) |
|  A2 |        C4 |     0 |    (null) |
|  A2 |        C5 |     0 |    (null) |
```

Comment: C2 is BOM type item, it will linked to C6 and C7, C7 is BOM type item, it will linked to C8, C9 and C10.  For BOM A1 records, can A1-C3, and A1-C7 records be suppressed from result?  I need the result on the component field is raw material items only.

Comment: I use the code below which can eliminate A1-C3 and A1-C7.
    -- Statement that executes the CTE
    SELECT X.BOM, X.Component, X.Level
FROM DirectReports AS X
LEFT JOIN DirectReports AS Y
on X.Component = Y.BOM
where Y.BOM IS NULL
ORDER BY X.BOM

Comment: @YellowLarry Sorry I dont understand anything you said. Can you show me an example? Edit the question and let me know. But im going to bed now so only can check tomorrow.

Comment: I just dont understand why you dont want show C1, C2 together with A1, A2 if both are `BOM`  (btw what mean BOM) .... or you want `BOM` that arent part of any other component?

Comment: After editing my question, now I  understand your second comment. So isnt that solve your issue?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, The only difference between your output and the needed one seems to be C2 and C7. As far as I understand these two should not pop up, as they are followed by components themselves... The OP wants the very last components only... (=leaf only).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think it was enough to add this to your `WHERE`: `AND DR.Component IN 
(
 SELECT outerTbl.Component
 FROM @tbl AS outerTbl
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl AS innerTbl WHERE outerTbl.Component=innerTbl.BOM)
)`

Comment: @Shnugo I understand what you said, but dont see that on the question. I think OP should put an example of desire output. I refuse to spend more time until OP do that. Otherwise is just a guessing game

Comment: Output records are included on the question.

Comment: My output is exact to that one. Why havent you accepted as the correct answer?

Comment: With @Shnugo May 16 21:20 comments, the result is correct.

Comment: @YellowLarry Glad you could solve, for me still was cofused on what result you want. Please try to describe your example with more detail next time  to help us find one answer for you.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.  Yes, I should had result on my question when I posted my question.  btw, BOM is bill of materials.  Wikipedia has detail information - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials.  Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This will not go down to any level, but the idea is simple and you can add as many levels as you like

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(BOM VARCHAR(10), Component VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('A1','C1')
,('A1','C2')
,('A1','C3')

,('A2','C4')
,('A2','C5')

,('C2','C6')
,('C2','C7')

,('C7','C8')
,('C7','C9')
,('C7','C10');

WITH rCTE AS
(
    SELECT tbl.BOM,tbl.Component,1 AS Level
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE Component=tbl.BOM)    

    UNION ALL

    SELECT nxt.BOM,nxt.Component,rCTE.Level+1
    FROM rCTE
    INNER JOIN @tbl AS nxt ON rCTE.Component=nxt.BOM 
)
SELECT lvl1.BOM AS l1
      ,ISNULL(lvl1.Component,lvl2.BOM) AS l2
      ,ISNULL(lvl2.Component,lvl3.BOM) AS l3
      ,ISNULL(lvl3.Component,lvl4.BOM) AS l4

FROM rCTE AS lvl1
LEFt JOIN rCTE AS lvl2 ON lvl1.Component=lvl2.BOM AND lvl2.Level=2
LEFt JOIN rCTE AS lvl3 ON lvl2.Component=lvl3.BOM AND lvl3.Level=3
LEFt JOIN rCTE AS lvl4 ON lvl3.Component=lvl4.BOM AND lvl4.Level=4
WHERE lvl1.Level=1
```

The result

```
+----+----+------+------+
| A1 | C1 | NULL | NULL |
+----+----+------+------+
| A1 | C2 | C6   | NULL |
+----+----+------+------+
| A1 | C2 | C7   | C8   |
+----+----+------+------+
| A1 | C2 | C7   | C9   |
+----+----+------+------+
| A1 | C2 | C7   | C10  |
+----+----+------+------+
| A1 | C3 | NULL | NULL |
+----+----+------+------+
| A2 | C4 | NULL | NULL |
+----+----+------+------+
| A2 | C5 | NULL | NULL |
+----+----+------+------+
```

### UPDATE

If you change the final `SELECT` to this

```
SELECT lvl1.BOM AS l1
      ,COALESCE
      (
           --add more levels top down
           ISNULL(lvl3.Component,lvl4.BOM)
          ,ISNULL(lvl2.Component,lvl3.BOM)
          ,ISNULL(lvl1.Component,lvl2.BOM)
      ) AS Comp

FROM rCTE AS lvl1
LEFt JOIN rCTE AS lvl2 ON lvl1.Component=lvl2.BOM AND lvl2.Level=2
LEFt JOIN rCTE AS lvl3 ON lvl2.Component=lvl3.BOM AND lvl3.Level=3
LEFt JOIN rCTE AS lvl4 ON lvl3.Component=lvl4.BOM AND lvl4.Level=4
--add more levels
WHERE lvl1.Level=1
```

You would get this, which seems to be pretty close to the thing you need...

```
A1  C1
A1  C6
A1  C8
A1  C9
A1  C10
A1  C3
A2  C4
A2  C5
```

Comment: Updated SELECT result is what I need.  Thanks.